# Hacer aparecer un div y desaparecer otro elemento cuando un botón esta en hover

Tags: css, html5

Al hacer *hover* en el botón aparecen los elementos ocultos, lo que busco hacer es que al mismo tiempo que aparecen estos elementos ocultos, desaparezca un elemento que está visible (icono-6).

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
/* Elementos ocultos */
.hidef {
  color: white;
  position:absolute;
  opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
transition: opacity 600ms, visibility 600ms;
line-height: 150%;
}

/* Boton */
.myDIVf {    
    color: white;
    font-weight: 200;
    letter-spacing: 1.8px;
    fill: #FFFFFF;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: rgba(2, 1, 1, 0);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}


/* Hover del Boton */
.myDIVf:hover {  
      color: #052532;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-top: -7px;
    transition: all .3s;
}

 
/* Icono */ 
.img6 {
  margin-top:-278px;
  margin-left: 64px;
  width: 48%;
}


/* Titulo */
.img6-2 {
  margin-top:-245px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
    
/* Hover para mostrar elementos ocultos */
.myDIVf:hover + .hidef {
 color: white;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    line-height: 150%;
}
```

Busco que el elemento icono-6 desaparezca al hacer *hover* en el botón para que los elementos ocultos aparezcan en el mismo sitio que icono-6 para que no aparezcan encima de el elemento icono-6.

Comment: Hola. No se de casos de uso que logren ese efecto usando sólo css. En mi experiencia hace falta agregar algo de javascript para responder a los eventos mouseenter mouseleave (ligados al estado hover) y provocar el efecto deseado. Revisa [Bootstrap collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar javascript. Puedes hacer lo siguiente. Te recomiendo usar id en lugar de clases para un solo objeto para no tener ningún problema. Espero haber ayudado un poco a tu pregunta.

```js
let boton = document.getElementById('myDIVf');
let div = document.getElementById('div');
let icono = document.getElementById('img6');

boton.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  div.style.display = "block"; //Puedes usar inline o cualquier otro
  icono.style.display = "none"; 
});

boton.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  div.style.display = "none";
  icono.style.display = "block"; 
});
```

```css
#div {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">Esto es un div</div>
<h2 id="img6">Icono</h2>
<button id="myDIVf">Hover</button>
```

Comment: Buen código, me viene bien para mi recopilación de funciones.